# Swift: How can I detect elements inside of a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am wondering two things (I am a Swift beginner):

1) Is there a way to detect or target elements (children) are inside a give `UIView`.

2) Are the elements inside the `UIView` stored in an array?

As an example let say I have a `UIView` called parentView and it has inside an `ImageView` (called `imageChildre`) and a `LabelView` (called `labelChildre`)

How can I target the children?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Something like this? You can change condition accordingly.

   ```
   for subview in parentView.subviews
   {
       if let item = subview as? UIImageView
       {
           //this is image view
       }
   }
   ```
2. `parentView.subviews` is an array of views inside `parentView`

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> 1) Is there a way to detect or target elements (children) are inside a give `UIView`.

Generally, you hook up [outlets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html) to those subviews in Interface Builder when you first designed the view.

Or if doing it programmatically, you'd keep a reference to the various subviews of the view as you programmatically added them to the view.

We'd need to know how you built this view and its subviews to advise further.

> 2) Are the elements inside the UIView stored in an array?

Yes, every `UIView` has a property called `subviews` which is all of those subviews of the view. But you wouldn't generally use this to access the subviews, but rather use the technique outlined in answer to your first question.

Comment: Thanks rob...that makes a lot of sense.