# Change UITextView text by using its tag number to identify the element due for change

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

```
//UITextView Creation
let textarea  = UITextView (frame : CGRect (x: 40, y: 100 ,width:100 , height:100))
                                            textarea.delegate = self
                                            textarea.tag = self.numarr
                                            textarea.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9686, green: 0.9686, blue: 0.9686, alpha: 1.0)
                                            textarea.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
                                            textarea.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
                                            textarea.layer.masksToBounds = true
                                            self.scrollviewxp.addSubview(textarea)   

//Later after, the button function
 @IBAction func loadbutton(_ sender: Any) {

if let hellatextview = self.scrollviewxp.viewWithTag(index) as? UITextView
                        {

                            hellatextview.text = "success"
                        }

                                         }
```

The above code is not flagged as an error on Xcode but doesn't change the UITextView (hellatextview) value upon execution. A textView with a tag number (index) exists but isn't being changed.

Any ideas why it isn't working? Ive had the same issue with UIButtons

Comment: where you are calling this chunk of code?

Comment: @adarshaU Once a user presses a button (loadbutton) the code inside the loadbutton function is fired. Ive edited the question for you to see.

Comment: is hellatextview.text = "success" this part getting fired ?

Comment: This particular part doesnt fire ie doesn't change the text.
The if statement works tho, tested it by adding 'print("its fired")' inside. The debug console shows the printed text("Its fired").

Comment: Is that your actual code? Or are you running some other calls before `hellatextview.text = "success"`? The fact your func is named "loadbutton" indicates to me that you are *loading something from somewhere* and *then* trying to change the text... and *that* may be where the problem lies.

Comment: @DonMang The above code format works with UIlabels but not UIButtons, UITextViews and UITextFields (so far).

Comment: Is the loadbutton function called by the user clicking the button or do you call it manually somewhere (that it might be a main thread issue)?
And also see that you set the delegate to self, what can you show us the implementation of the text view delegate methods?

Comment: What exception do you get? And do you call loadbutton in main thread?

Comment: @Nef10 Setting the delegate doesn't work either( tested it with UIButtons too). The textview is altered by the method  *func textViewDidChange(_ textarea: UITextView){ }* which is elsewhere in my code (Its executed when the user starts typing). The function mentioned in the question runs once a user presses a button (loadbutton)

Comment: @tereks I don't get an exception or crash of any sort (maybe because the if statement is valid and produces a boolean result)

Comment: ok, I assume you have several UITextViews and want to change text in one of them. All UITextViews have the same coordinates and frame and maybe you set text in uitextview that covered by another textView?

Comment: @tereks Thats correct, I want to change only one. All the UITextViews have unique coordinates and frames. Its definitely not an overlap of UITextViews.

Comment: Then sorry. You can try using *scrollviewxp.subviews.first(where: { $0.tag == index})* and set breakpoint in if statement

Comment: @tereks Thanks to ur piece of code I was able to find something that works! Found some thing similar to what you are saying here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591058/swift-how-can-i-detect-elements-inside-of-a-uiview Thanks Heaps!

Comment: @terek Please submit an answer similar to mine. Thanks for the help.  Will acknowledge ur answer as the official answer because its legitimate and safe.

Comment: @KhanLuke viewWithTag had return you the view with tag, and indeed it searching whole hierarchy in recursion (all subviews among subviews). However it is not recommended to identify you view using tag. It can fail if you have multiple views with same tag, or view you are looking for not in hierarchy. Why do want to use so error prone and ineffective method in first place?

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov If you wish to use tags as unique identifiers for views, then make sure every tag is unique. Thats all there is to it. Its definite and 100% accurate.
How else would you identify a view?

Comment: @KhanLuke IBOutlet, IBOutletCollection - if you are taking them from InterfaceBuilder,   private variable (array/dictionary) in case you creating them dynamically, tableview or collection view, if you are using large collections. Identifying view by tags is very bad practice and had to be used only if other obvious choices can be used.

Answer (score 4):

> You only need to make sure that the `scrollviewxp` is the very
>   superview for the view trying to get with `tag`.

***Otherwise, there is absolutely 0 reasons to fail.***

Comment: It is. The scroll view - scrollviewxp - is inside a view controller (this view controller is linked to its designated class)  and the UItextview due for change is inside the scrollview mentioned.

Comment: Also tried self.view.viewwithTag instead of self.scrollviewxp.viewwithTag but its no good.

Comment: Are you sure that you don’t have another inner view inside your scroll view then your views with tags?

Answer (score 4):

SWIFT 4 Working solutions:

1.

```
if let hellaTextView = scrollviewxp.subviews.first(where: { $0.tag == index }) as? UITextView {
    hellaTextView.text = "success"
}
```

or

2.

```
   for subview in scrollviewxp.subviews
{
   if let hellatextview.text = subview as? UITextView 
     {
         if hellatextview.tag == index {
         hellatextview.text = "success"
                              }
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Khan Luke How come you change correct answer to another user?